# How to add text to a gif node.js

Tags: node.js, gif, animated-gif

I am dealing with a problem. I want to download a gif and place text at the top for example add the text "Top text" on [this gif](https://tenor.com/6mBn.gif).

I have looked through [google](https://google.com) codegrepper and stackoverflow for an answer but nothing

How would i accomplish that? Documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: @ShivenDhir personally i don't know. It's maybe because it had typos that's why i decided to edit it so i can post questions

Comment: Maybe you could try adding a little more detail on code examples on what you have tried. If your problem is solved, adding a "solution" section to the bottom of the answer may improve the upvotes on the answer. Also, why have you linked to StackOverflow?

Comment: @ShivenDhir no idea.

Comment: It's really not needed. Obviously someone on StackOverflow has the link to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tenorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tenorjs) to fetch the GIFs. If you only want to use one certain GIF, you download that, and add that to your Files.

You can use something like [text-on-gif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-on-gif) to display text on the GIF.

Basic Usage of `text-on-gif`:

```js
const textOnGif = require("text-on-gif");

(async function(){

    //get gif as buffer
    var gifBuffer = await textOnGif({
            file_path:"/path/file.gif", //path to local file or url
            textMessage:"custom message"
        });
    console.log(gifBuffer)

    //write gif as file
    await textOnGif({
        file_path:"/path/file.gif", //path to local file or url
        textMessage:"custom message",
        write_as_file:true,
        getAsBuffer:false,
        write_path:"path/gif-with-text.gif"
    });

})();
```

Comment: The funny thing is i found the text-on-gif RIGHT after posting this